# Using TypeScript, styled-components and PostCSS with webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, styled-components, postcss

I use webpack to build a react application using styled-components written in TypeScript. I also use PostCSS with autoprefixer to support CSS grids on older browsers. The compilation works but the generated sourcemaps aren't correct. If I view them in Chrome the "original source" shows the output of PostCSS instead of the original tsx-source. Here is my webpack.config.js (sourcemaps are enabled in tsconfig.json):

```
module.exports = {
   mode: "development",
   entry: {
      "GridTest.js": "./Source/View/GridTest.tsx",
   },
   output: {
      filename: "../../bmdnet/js/packed/[name]"
   },
   devtool: "source-map",
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: [
               {
                  loader: "ts-loader",
               },
               {
                  loader: "postcss-loader",
                  options: {
                     plugins: () => ([
                        require("autoprefixer")({ grid: true }),
                        require("postcss-fail-on-warn"),
                     ]),
                     syntax: "postcss-jsx",
                     sourceMap: true,
                  },
               },
            ],
         },
      ]
   },
};
```

This is my test file GridTest.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const GridTest = styled(() => <div />)`
& {
   display: grid;
}
`;
```

This is the "original source" of GridTest.tsx as shown for e.g. in Chrome dev tools:

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const GridTest = styled(() => <div />)`
& {
   display: -ms-grid; // this line should not be here
   display: grid;   
}
`;
```

I can't find any information about how webpack generates source maps when using multiple loaders. I assumed webpack would apply the first source map (from postcss-loader) to the second sourcemap (from ts-loader) and generate a final source map that points from the final output to the original file which unfortunately does not seem to be the case. I debugged the source of the ts-loader and the source map from postcss-loader is passed to it, but the ts-loader does not use it and assumes it's input is the original source.

This is not too bad when debugging in Chrome but it is terrible when compilation fails and a wrong line number is shown. I don't even know if the second problem can be solved using source maps.

I already tried reversing the order of ts-loader and postcss-loader but postcss-jsx does obviously not work after the transformation into plain JavaScript.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?